# Cannot set global value for attribute AMD Radeon HD 6450

Tags: opengl, glsl

I use simple vertex shader with just two attributes.

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;
out vec3 pass_Color;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

    pass_Color = in_Color;
}
```

For drawing wireframe I'd like to disable `in_Color` and set black color for it.

My code for this purposes:

```
//Setups

GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(in_Color_Location);
GL.VertexAttrib3(in_Color_Location, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

//Drawing calls
```

This applications works perfect on my computers with NVidia Quadro 2000 and NVidia GeForce GT 650M. It looks strange that same application doesn't work on AMD Radeon HD 6450.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: From what you have shown so far, it _should_ work. This _might_ be some driver bug. Have you made sure a recent driver is installed?

Comment: @derhass: really, it should. And it works, but not on my AMD Radeon. I already have installed latest drivers and check system with OpenGL Extensions Viewer. So far Extensions Viewer shows that everything is ok.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have encountered this before (constant attribute value seemingly ignored) and put it down to a driver bug. Sorry I can't remember the hardware I was using at the time.